# In jQuery, how to find all elements matching given strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out how to select all `<span class="title">` elements on the page:

```
<div class="my-page">
    <span class="title">first</span>
    <span class="title">second</span>
    <span class="title">third</span>
    <span class="title">fourth</span>
    <span class="title">fifth</span>
</div>
```

that are present on the list (fetched from servlet in JSON format) and stored inside some variable?

I've tried something like:

```
success : function(data, statusText, jqxhr) {
  var arr = data.selectedTitles;
    jQuery.each(data.favTools, function(i, v) {
      var title = v;
      jQuery('span.title:contains(title)').css("text-decoration", "underline");
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: you mean, the list is fetched from the server and from THAT you want to find all spans?

Comment: @ParthThakkar Yes. Don't ask my why this work isn't done on the server side.

Comment: i won't. but can you show the JSON data that's returned? just a dummy version?

Comment: ok, wait. so, you mean that spans are already there, and JSON returns which of those needs to be selected? right? sorry if repeated questions annoy you

Comment: @ParthThakkar Exactly, but ThiefMaster already helped me. Anyway I really appreciate your willingness to help me, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('span.title').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(title) != -1;
});
```